# remote mysql access showing different database list

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I found a weird problem that when I connect to my database which locates at another server, the output of `show databases;` was different with that when I did local.

My database was running MySQL at IP 10.200.0.11, I connect with `mysql -u username -p -h 10.200.0.11`

I did some search, seems no people reported this problem? Did my mysql client cached something? I tried another client machine, and it works good through.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: my bad....I did `GRANT ALL privileges ON newdatbase.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;` and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`, now the output were same now...but I am still confused another client get same output before I did the `grant` command...